# Nested While loop that creates directories with sub directories in Python

Tags: python, directory

I'm trying to write a nested while loop that will create n number of folders with n number of sub-directories. The problem with my current code is that the first folder created does not contain the sub-directories. Only the 2nd directory made contains the sub-directories. My goal is to write a program that runs a parametric sweep with groundwater modeling software, and I need these directories to save the results.

```
import subprocess, os

i = 1
j = 1
while i <= 2:
    path = r'C:/Users/TEvans/Desktop/Testing/slope%d' % i 
    if not os.path.exists(path): os.makedirs(path)
    os.chdir(path)
    i = i+1
    while j <= 3:
        path1 = r'C:/Users/TEvans/Desktop/Testing/slope%d/r%d' % (i, j)
        if not os.path.exists(path1): os.makedirs(path1)
        j = j+1
```

Comment: The `os.chdir(path)` is not required. The `os.makedirs(path)` in the outer loop is not required. The call to `os.makedirs(path1)` in the inner loop will create the `slope%d` directory if it does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

Some of your code is redundant, and (as others mentioned) the `while` is confusing your math.

Here is a simpler, nearly equivalent version:

```
import os
for i in (1,2):
  for j in (1,2,3):
    path1 = r'C:/Users/TEvans/Desktop/Testing/slope%d/r%d' % (i, j)
    if not os.path.exists(path1): os.makedirs(path1)
```

- I removed the call to `os.makedirs()` in the outer loop since those directories will be created by the inner loop's `os.makedirs()`.
- I fixed the math for both `i` and `j` to reflect what I believe you intended.
- I removed the call to `os.chdir()` because you are using absolute paths and the call appeared to be otherwise unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

When `os.makedirs(path1)` is called for the first time `i` is already incremented. If you used a foor loop the code would be not only cleaner but more correct.

Comment: Thank you! I moved the increment for the first loop and it works.

Comment: Consider using `for` with `xrange`. I don't see reasons for `while` here.

Comment: Ok I'll switch to a for loop. When is a while loop handy? I almost never use them.

Comment: @Tbevans88 when you don't loop over an iterable or when you need something other than incrementing the iterator at the end of the loop body.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `i` has already been incremented before the inner while loop is entered, you could fix this by moving the `i = i+1` line so that it is the last thing that is done in the `while i <= 2` loop.

However a better solution would be to just use a for loop:

```
for i in range(1, 3):
    path = r'C:/Users/TEvans/Desktop/Testing/slope%d' % i 
    if not os.path.exists(path): os.makedirs(path)
    os.chdir(path)
    for j in range(1, 4):
        path1 = r'C:/Users/TEvans/Desktop/Testing/slope%d/r%d' % (i, j)
        if not os.path.exists(path1): os.makedirs(path1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the loop constructs.
This should do the trick:

```
import subprocess, os

for i in range(0,2):
    path = r'C:/Users/TEvans/Desktop/Testing/slope%d' % i 
    if not os.path.exists(path): os.makedirs(path)
    os.chdir(path)
    for j in range(0,3):
        path1 = r'C:/Users/TEvans/Desktop/Testing/slope%d/r%d' % (i, j)
        if not os.path.exists(path1): os.makedirs(path1)
```

The 'for' construct ensures that the variable is only incremented after the entire code-block has been executed, in stead of somewhere in between, as is the case in your code fragment.